# Get a link to a specific line in a diff using GitHub API?

Tags: github, diff, github-api

Using the GitHub API I'm looking for a way to generate a link to a specific line in a diff.

I can already contruct a "compare between commits" url, for example:
https://github.com/emmetog/feature-flags/compare/master...d8f9c29bfd0b87d26123b78b76feca8e4c87ad8

And visiting that url in a browser I can click on a specific line and I get this:
https://github.com/emmetog/feature-flags/compare/master...d8f9c29bfd0b87d26123b78b76feca8e4c87ad8#diff-21171d4ef87ca8e3591556dd18dfa456R26

However, I need to generate that last bit, the `#diff-21171d4ef87ca8e3591556dd18dfa456R26` bit, programatically throught the github api, or else find another way of linking to the specific line in the diff without going through the browser.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**It is impossible.**

1. I read https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits
2. I tried 
   `curl https://github.com/emmetog/feature-flags/compare/master...d8f9c29bfd0b87d26123b78b76feca8e4c87ad8`
3. By using GitHub API, we can not specify what is the line 26th of different between new version and old version of file `src/Emmetog/FeatureFlag/Entity/FeatureFlag.php`
   Because difference of 2 revisions doesn't happen at line 26, it is impossible for comparing. Or file `src/Emmetog/FeatureFlag/Entity/FeatureFlag.php` has only 10 lines of code, it is impossible for comparing.
4. In HTML webpage, id = `diff-21171d4ef87ca8e3591556dd18dfa456R26` is auto-generated id. We can not specify intentional way before executing GitHub API request.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to do it, but it looks like you can do some webscraping.

For example. In the link you provided. That line contains this element:

```
<td id="diff-21171d4ef87ca8e3591556dd18dfa456R26"
data-line-number="26" class="blob-num blob-num-addition
js-linkable-line-number selected-line"></td>
```

Which contains the diff hash. You also have the line number (26). Now you just need the 'R' between the diff hash and the line number. That, I believe, is given by whether the line has been added or removed. You can get that from the css class 'blob-num-addition'. It looks like 'blob-num-addition' corresponds to 'R' and 'blob-num-addition' corresponds to 'L'